# i have a problem with making the game of rock,paper,scissors in code blocks(c language)

Tags: c, while-loop, codeblocks

everything in the code works exept the while loop, and I couldn't figure out how to fix it
code(it's a bit messy):

```
float paper1 = 1, rock1 = 3, scissors1 = 2, paper2 = -1, rock2 = -3,
      scissors2 = -2, life1 = 3, life2 = 3, number1, number2, result;
printf("first player, choose a number\n");
scanf("%f", &number1);
if (number1 == 3) {
    printf("you choose rock\n");
} else if (number1 == 2) {
    printf("you choose scissors\n");
} else if (number1 == 1) {
    printf("you choose paper\n");
} else {
    printf("you choose the wrong number\n");
}
printf("second player, choose a number\n");
scanf("%f", &number2);
if (number2 == -3) {
    printf("you choose rock\n");
} else if (number2 == -2) {
    printf("you choose scissors\n");
} else if (number2 == -1) {
    printf("you choose paper\n");
} else {
    printf("you choose the wrong number\n");
}
if (number1 == number2) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else if (number1 > 3) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else if (number2 < -3) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else if (number1 < 0) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else if (number2 > 0) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else if (number1 / number2 == -1) {
    life2 = -1;
    life1 = -1;
} else {
    life1 = 3;
    life2 = 3;
}
result = scissors2 - paper1 + 10;
result = rock2 - scissors1 + 10;
result = paper2 - rock1 + 12;
result = scissors1 - paper2 + 10;
result = rock1 - scissors2 + 10;
result = paper1 - rock2 + 15;
while (life1 > 0, life2 > 0) {
    if (result == 7) {
        life1 = life1 - 1;
        printf("second player won a round\n");
    } else if (result == 6) {
        life1 = life1 - 1;
        printf("second player won a round\n");
    } else if (result == 8) {
        life1 = life1 - 1;
        printf("second player won a round\n");
    } else if (result == 13) {
        life2 = life2 - 1;
        printf("first player won a round\n");
    } else if (result == 15) {
        life2 = life2 - 1;
        printf("first player won a round\n");
    } else if (result == 18) {
        life2 = life2 - 1;
        printf("first player won a round\n");
    }
}
if (life1 == 0) {
    printf("player 1 lost\n");
} else if (life2 == 0) {
    printf("player 2 lost\n");
} else {
    printf("error\n");
}
if (life1 == -1 && life2 == -1) {
    printf("program not working\n");
}
```

I was trying to set up a condition for while loop where it subtracts one from eihter life1 or life2 and repeats the same process until it reaches 0
if life1 reaches zero first player one lost, same goes for player two with life2

Comment: Aside: why are you using `float` variables? Also, player two is entering negative values by the look of it. So how will `if(number1==number2)` ever be true?

Comment: Use `while (life1>0 && life2>0)`

Comment: There are 6 consecutive lines each setting `result` to a different value. This code is ... bizarre.

Comment: in the code i don't want for player one to enter a negative number or player two a positive number

Comment: "Aside: why are you using float variables? Also, player two is entering negative values by the look of it. So how will if(number1==number2) ever be true?" they are never meant to be the same

Comment: The entry of each player's choice is NOT inside the `while()` loop... Cannot expect there to be multiple "rounds" of play...

Comment: The messages confirm that player 1 has selected 'rock' etc with a positive value, and that player 2 has chosen with a negative value, any thing else is a "wrong number". So, they are never equal.

Comment: The calculation of `result` takes no account of the player's entry...

Comment: This line `while(life1>0, life2>0)` does not do what you might be expecting. The loop is controlled **only** by `life2>0`. Did you mean `while(life1>0 && life2>0)` or even `while(life1>0 || life2>0)`?

Comment: "The entry of each player's choice is NOT inside the while() loop... Cannot expect there to be multiple "rounds" of play..." I put them inside the while loop and it still doesn't work

Comment: Welcome, it is expected that you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. And post the inputs, the expected output and the actual output. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"everything in the code works_"?  You are being somewhat generous to yourself.  It all looks a bit "cargo cult" to me.

Comment: "_it's a bit messy_"  Messy code is hard to debug (and generally contains more bugs) so perhaps you should address that issue first?  The algorithm does not demonstrate clear thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you put the code for handling one game round into its own function. Let's call this function `do_game_round`. Depending on the outcome of the round, the function should return an `enum` whose value is either

- `ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER1_WINS`,
- `ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER2_WINS` or
- `ROUND_RESULT_TIE`.

The code which calls this function can then look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum round_result
{
    ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER1_WINS,
    ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER2_WINS,
    ROUND_RESULT_TIE
};

enum round_result do_game_round( void )
{
    //In this function, you should put all the code which handles
    //one game round. For simplicity, I am using the following
    //placeholer code which assumes that player 1 always wins.
    printf( "Performing game round, which Player 1 wins.\n");
    return ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER1_WINS;
}

int main( void )
{
    int life1 = 3, life2 = 3;

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        switch ( do_game_round() )
        {
            case ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER1_WINS:
                life2--;
                if ( life2 == 0 )
                {
                    printf( "Player 2 is out of lives, Player 1 wins the entire game!\n" );
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf( "Player 2 now has %d lives.\n", life2 );
                }
                break;
            case ROUND_RESULT_PLAYER2_WINS:
                life1--;
                if ( life1 == 0 )
                {
                    printf( "Player 1 is out of lives, Player 2 wins the entire game!\n" );
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf( "Player 1 now has %d lives.\n", life1 );
                }
                break;
            case ROUND_RESULT_TIE:
                //do nothing
                break;
            default:
                fprintf( stderr, "Unexpected return value!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
}
```

This demonstration program has the following output:

```
Performing game round, which Player 1 wins.
Player 2 now has 2 lives.
Performing game round, which Player 1 wins.
Player 2 now has 1 lives.
Performing game round, which Player 1 wins.
Player 2 is out of lives, Player 1 wins the entire game!
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your question about the while loop, you have a loop around the result of a single round, so it is not going to iterate multiple rounds, moreover the test:

```
while (life1 > 0, life2 > 0)
```

is syntactically valid whilst being semantic nonsense.  The `life2 > 0` is evaluated but discarded.  You need the `&&` (Boolean AND) operator, not the comma operator.

```
while (life1 > 0 && life2 > 0)
```

First however, I suggest that you fix the "*messy*" code. Messy code is harder to debug, hard for others to understand your intent, and statistically will contain more bugs.  Both the code and the *algorithm* is messy - and exceptionally hard to understand.  To be honest, I did not bother to try to understand it - it is rather more complicated than is necessary for this very simple game.

Consider for example, if you represent Rock, Paper and Scissors by the integer values 0, 1 and 2 respectively, then the result of a single game can be determined by:

```
int winner = ((player1 - player2) + 3) % 3 ;
```

This works because:

[image]

A simple "modulo 3" circular arithmetic relationship where the result is zero for a draw, 1 if player 1 wins and 2 if player 2 wins.

I further suggest that you encapsulate the player choice into a function and use the same code for both players.  For example:

```
int playerSelection()
{
    #define INVALID_SELECTION sizeof(rps)
    static const char rps[] = {'r', 'p', 's'} ;
    int selection = INVALID_SELECTION ;
        
    // While selection is not one of R,P,S,r,p or s...
    while( selection == INVALID_SELECTION )
    {
        printf("Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: ");
    
        char ch = 0 ;
        scanf("%c", &ch ) ;
        while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) ;
    
        // Transform input to one of 0,1,2 (for R,P,S respectively)
        for( selection = 0; 
             selection < INVALID_SELECTION && tolower(ch) != rps[selection] ; 
             selection++ )
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    
    return selection ;
}
```

Then your player selection might look like:

```
    // Get player selections    
    int player1 = playerSelection() ;
    int player2 = playerSelection() ;
```

Now given the player selection and the determination of a "winner", you can put that whole in a loop, where you decrement the life count of the *loosing* player until one player has zero lives remaining. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int player1_lives = 3 ;
    int player2_lives = 3 ;
    int rounds_played = 0 ;
        
    // While both players live...
    while(player1_lives > 0 && player2_lives > 0 )
    {
        // Get player selections  
        printf( "Player 1: " ) ;
        int player1 = playerSelection() ;

        printf( "Player 2: " ) ;
        int player2 = playerSelection() ;

        rounds_played++ ;
        
        // Report player selections in full text
        static const char* play_lookup[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" } ;
        printf( "Player one played %s\n", play_lookup[player1] ) ;
        printf( "Player two played %s\n", play_lookup[player2] ) ;
    
        // Calculate and report result
        int winner = ((player1 - player2) + 3) % 3 ;
        if( winner == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Round %d was a draw!\n\n", rounds_played ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Player %d wins round %d\n\n", winner, rounds_played ) ; 
            if( winner == 1 )
            {
                player2_lives-- ;
            }
            else
            {
                player1_lives-- ;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf( "Player %d won the game in %d rounds.", player1_lives != 0 ? 1 : 2, 
                                                    rounds_played ) ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Example game play:

```
Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Player one played Rock
Player two played Paper
Player 2 wins round 1

Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Player one played Paper
Player two played Scissors
Player 2 wins round 2

Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Player one played Scissors
Player two played Paper
Player 1 wins round 3

Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: s
Player one played Scissors
Player two played Scissors
Round 4 was a draw!

Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Player one played Paper
Player two played Rock
Player 1 wins round 5

Player 1: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: r
Player 2: Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: p
Player one played Rock
Player two played Paper
Player 2 wins round 6

Player 2 won the game in 6 rounds.
```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int playerSelection() ;

int main()
{
    int player1_lives = 3 ;
    int player2_lives = 3 ;
    int rounds_played = 0 ;
        
    // While both players live...
    while(player1_lives > 0 && player2_lives > 0 )
    {
        // Get player selections  
        printf( "Player 1: " ) ;
        int player1 = playerSelection() ;

        printf( "Player 2: " ) ;
        int player2 = playerSelection() ;

        rounds_played++ ;
        
        // Report player selections in full text
        static const char* play_lookup[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" } ;
        printf( "Player one played %s\n", play_lookup[player1] ) ;
        printf( "Player two played %s\n", play_lookup[player2] ) ;
    
        // Calculate and report result
        int winner = ((player1 - player2) + 3) % 3 ;
        if( winner == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Round %d was a draw!\n\n", rounds_played ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Player %d wins round %d\n\n", winner, rounds_played ) ; 
            if( winner == 1 )
            {
                player2_lives-- ;
            }
            else
            {
                player1_lives-- ;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf( "Player %d won the game in %d rounds.", player1_lives != 0 ? 1 : 2, rounds_played ) ;
    
    return 0;
}


int playerSelection()
{
    #define INVALID_SELECTION sizeof(rps)
    static const char rps[] = {'r', 'p', 's'} ;
    int selection = INVALID_SELECTION ;
        
    // While selection is not one of R,P,S,r,p or s...
    while( selection == INVALID_SELECTION )
    {
        printf("Enter R for Rock, P for Paper, or S for Scissors: ");
    
        char ch = 0 ;
        scanf("%c", &ch ) ;
        while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) ;
    
        // Transform input to one of 0,1,2 (for R,P,S respectively)
        for( selection = 0; 
             selection < INVALID_SELECTION && tolower(ch) != rps[selection] ; 
             selection++ )
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    
    return selection ;
}
```

Changing the "win" rules for example "*best of 5*, "_first to 10", or the adding of a life on a win as well as decrementing on a loose for example for example is easily implemented using this general framework, so if I have misunderstood the intended "*rules*" you should be able to adapt it to suit.